# The site description in the hero header is wrong for per site metas

Tags: bug, per-site-meta, wording, notification-bar

The hero header contains the same description for the main and meta sites. Here's the one for Meta Stack Overflow:

> [image]
>
> Meta Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. It only takes a minute to sign up.

This can easily confuse people who are new to the network, so I feel this should be changed to something meta specific. Perhaps re-use the text from the sidebar, that has a good description:

> This site is intended for **bugs, features, and discussion** of [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/) and the software that powers it. You must have an account on Stack Overflow to participate.

Comment: Hero Header? What's that? Are you referring to the Tour?

Comment: @DavidPostill [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WPgqZ.png), you can see it by opening a private browsing window.

Comment: Come to think of it, I'm not 100% sure that banner is supposed to show up on meta sites in the first place.

Comment: @AdamLear What's the official name of the header? Is it really "hero header"?

Comment: @RandomPerson: That appears to be it.. According to [Optimizely](https://www.optimizely.com/optimization-glossary/hero-image/#:~:text=A%20hero%20image%20is%20a,that%20usually%20extends%20full%2Dwidth.): *A hero image is a website design term used to describe an oversized banner image at the top of a website. Sometimes called a “hero header”, it serves as a user's first glimpse of your company and offering because of its prominent placement towards the top of a webpage that usually extends full-width.* (Personally, I would simply refer to it as a "banner".)

Answer (score 3):

I have an idea regarding some other text which can be placed in the hero header (inspired from [Meta Stack Exchange](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6f95k.png)). For example, this can be used in Ask Ubuntu Meta's hero header:

> Ask Ubuntu Meta is a question and answer site for meta-discussion of Ask Ubuntu. To ask about Ubuntu, go to Ask Ubuntu.