# What's the process of changing site description?

Tags: support, wording, site-description

Currently all the SO family sites have similar taglines, except SO in Russian:

> [image: List of Stack Overflow sites in various languages. The Portuguese and Spanish sites have a site description that translates to the same as the English site: "For professional and enthusiast programers"), but the Russian site description translates as: "For programmers"]

What's the procedure of changing such taglines for SE sites in general?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start a discussion on the corresponding per-site meta. It might be a good idea to ask a mod to add the [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) tag.

Once it gets enough feedback and community support, ask a mod to tag it as [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) (or post a new [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) with this tag, linking back to the prior discussion).

It's the same process for any change that requires the intervention of the CM Team. There should be a post from Catija, JNat, or someone else on the CM Team with the above.

IIRC, technically, changing the site description used to be slightly different than changing the site design, as the site description is hardcoded in several files, i.e., Data Explorer, etc. I don't know if that changed, but that is irrelevant to requesting the change. The relevance is when [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) is set [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed). You might like to look at the other places and contact the assigned CM to ask if it will be necessary to create a new [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) / guidance about handling the missing pieces.

Addendum:

Once your site description request is approved, it might be worth having a list of places where it should be updated (eventually).

- The site description is sometimes called the site tagline or site blurb.
- By "default", the site description is included in the site's tour. Remember that there are some parts of the site's tour and from the site's Help Center that site moderators can edit, so editing the site description in those places might not require a designer or developer. However, making a meta post on the corresponding per-child meta is still required.
- The site description is composed of the "audience" property of a [site object](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/site). The [/sites method](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/sites) of the Stack Exchange API returns the list of the Stack Exchange sites.
- The site description appears on site lists. Site lists show the site description at https://stackexchange.com, https://data.stackexchange.com, and the site navigation is shown in the Stack Exchange toolbar.
- The site description is shown in the Today's Featured Site box on the https://stackexchange.com homepage.
- The site description is shown on the "hero header" shown to users who are not logged in.

IMO, it would be best to prioritize updating the site description on the site's tour and Help Center first, as the moderators could do this. The theme, as designers, could do this and will be seen by users visiting your site. Other places later, as the changes might be delayed due to the systems that should be updated, might affect other services because the changes are likely to be done on resources of general usage rather than resources specific to your community. Also, the developers assigned to such resources of general usage might have other priorities.

Related:

- [How can a site change the "tagline" that shows in the site dropdown?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/311631/289691)
- [The site description in the hero header is wrong for per site metas](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/314522/289691)
- [Responsive Design Themes - What can sites customize and how can they get changes implemented?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/319274/289691)
- [Effectiveness of site name / descriptions of sites for "power users"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/388388/289691)

Comment: It's not clear what does it mean "enough feedback and community support". How to count it? After that what is the way should be used to contact with CM: TL Chat, some option on contact page, or just put a [status-review] tag and wait (how long)?

Comment: @αλεχολυτ "enough feedback and community support" is one among many things about how Stack Exchange works, not having a simple, short, straightforward answer that could be written using simple English words. Please consider asking a specific question about that, as it should be done with follow-up questions.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ Regarding how to contact a CM, adding [tag:status-review] will trigger something that will notify someone from the CM team, who will do a quick check on the meta-post about what it is about, i.e., if something is missing, among other things. If something is unclear, like community support, the CM doing the initial review will add a comment providing feedback or contact the mod / site mod team. Otherwise, the initial CM internally will update the "ticket" so the feature request can be directed to the appropriate person / team.

Comment: Assume that the office hours are from Monday to Friday, from 9 am to 5 pm EST. Expect 2-3 business days (US holidays) to get a comment (acknowledge / feedback).  If nothing happens, ping a CM on TL or use the Contact form.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ: See this Q&A: [How is consensus determined on Meta sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/177550/335251) – Basically, we want to make sure that the community's had time to weigh in on the discussion, and that they generally agree on the proposed change. And as Rubén mentioned – adding the [status-review] tag automatically creates a Jira issue for us internally, which we can then send to the relevant CM subteam or product team to review and handle as appropriate.